# Add a javascript for posts

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I dont know anything about Javascript. I'm using Ignite theme in Wordpress. I tried to add a lightbox gallery in my site:
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/   > the "Zoom-gallery" example

So I put the html code in the post, the CSS in style.css, but I dont know where I have to put the javascript. I tried to past it (between script tags) inside the content-page.php, content.php, header.php, or footer.php but it didn't work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="zoom-gallery">
    <a href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3763/9204547649_0472680945_o.jpg" data-source="http://500px.com/photo/32736307" title="Into The Blue" style="width:193px;height:125px;">
        <img src="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3763/9204547649_7de96ee188_t.jpg" width="193" height="125">
    </a>
    <a href="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2856/9207329420_7f2a668b06_o.jpg" data-source="http://500px.com/photo/32554131" title="Light Sabre" style="width:82px;height:125px;">
        <img src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2856/9207329420_e485948b01_t.jpg" width="82px" height="125">
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-source-link {
    color: #98C3D1;
}

.mfp-with-zoom .mfp-container,
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready .mfp-container {
        opacity: 1;
}
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-ready.mfp-bg {
        opacity: 0.8;
}

.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing .mfp-container, 
.mfp-with-zoom.mfp-removing.mfp-bg {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.zoom-gallery').magnificPopup({
        delegate: 'a',
        type: 'image',
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        closeBtnInside: false,
        mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom mfp-img-mobile',
        image: {
            verticalFit: true,
            titleSrc: function(item) {
                return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="'+item.el.attr('data-source')+'" target="_blank">image source</a>';
            }
        },
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true,
            duration: 300, // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
            opener: function(element) {
                return element.find('img');
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find actual theme folder . There should be folder called "js" if not crate it put this script into some js file in that "js" folder and include it in file called index.php in same directory.

Comment: Thats ok I just installed Notpad++ and now its working. So do I have to add the script between <script> tags or alone in my test.js file? Also I dont get this: "and include it in file called index.php in same directory"

Comment: No you needn't . just put ready function into that js file save it and include into index.php using script tag.

Comment: It doesn't work. I probably did something wrong. I created a js file inside js folder, put the javascript, saved it. Then found the index.php which is in "Ignite" folder and put the script between script tags at the end of the file and saved it

Comment: @edou777  make sure that js file was included successful. In chrome open dev console and look for 404 errors.Or look page source .

Comment: Ok thats what I didn t get in your first answer. What do you mean by "include" js file in index.php?? What I did  was just past the javascript at the end of the index.php file.

Comment: I mean the following for example if you have test.js file under theme_name/js directory you should include that file in index.php like this.

<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/test.js"></script>

Comment: @edou777 saying "include js into php file" I mean this.. 

<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/test.js"></script>

where this line bloginfo('template_url'); will get url for actual theme.
And you do not need a folder inside a folder just put you js code into test,js file . That's it.

Comment: Ok I did it and I got this message in my chrome console:"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function"

Comment: Cool. Now you need that library. Take a look here
https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup

Comment: Ok I looked :) Now what do I have to do (dont forget javascript is totaly new for me !)

Comment: About how to use this library you can read here . http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

There is just one js file "query.magnific-popup.js"  and one "magnific-popup.css"  file.

Comment: I add the files but I got some errors. If you want to see go to my page. There is too much to past here

Comment: Do all steps as provided in docs http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html and ervery thing will work fine.

Comment: Ok I didn t know it would take so much steps to get this little popup effect. I ll erase all that codes and use a plugin even if its not perfect. Thanks for your help!